# Carousels slick.js : 'getSlick' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

i'm using Slick.js to make 2 caroussels connected, and they are syncronised.
Slick offers the possibility, at the section "**Slider Syncing**"
[slick.js website](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

But when i'm using it, it doesnt work, i'm getting an error:
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSlick' of undefined***

my code is :

```
$('#page-gravure .sliders .slides-show ul').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slides'
});

$('#page-gravure .sliders .slides ul').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slides-show',
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Please guys, can you help me ?

***EDIT***: [JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/89jnb6w8/)

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimum working example by using something like jsfiddle? =]

Comment: there's one on their website http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ in the middle of the home page at the section  "Slider Syncing" :)

Comment: A minimum working example of YOUR code, which causes the problem. Because then you make validating a solution to the problem as easy as possible.

Comment: hoo okey, i'll do that and add it.

Comment: the Jsfiddle is added to my question post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that both of your references for the synced slider `asNavFor: ...` are wrong. The reference should be the same as you do to construct each slide. So your constructor functions should be as follows:

```
$('#page-gravure .sliders .slides-show ul').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '#page-gravure .sliders .slides ul'
});

$('#page-gravure .sliders .slides ul').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '#page-gravure .sliders .slides-show ul',
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89jnb6w8/1/)

Cheers